# Query using JavaScript to display events by date in HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ajax, xquery

I am new to javascript and need help. I am not sure if I should use AJAX or Xquery.

I have an XML file that I want to pull all programs by date and building and only display Name, Room and Time in an HTML document.

I want to do this so that all the Monday June 13 events will show and then tomorrow the webpage will show Tuesday June 14, 2011 events, etc.

I copied part of the XML and the HTML to this post.

Please help. I am not sure how to do this.

Here a small sample of the XML since there were about 90 programs I shorted the list.

```
<ProgramList>
    <Program>
        <Name>English Conversation Group - Wed.  Morning</Name>
        <Building>Centereach</Building>
        <Room>Foundation Room</Room>
        <Date>6/14/2011</Date>
        <Time>9:30 AM-11:30 AM</Time>
    </Program>
    <Program>
        <Name>Family Center- One on One Counseling</Name>
        <Building>Selden</Building>
        <Room>Lower Meeting Room</Room>
        <Date>6/15/2011</Date>
        <Time>9:30 AM-4:00 PM</Time>
    </Program>
</ProgramList>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="nature2.js"></script> 
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" text="#444316">
    <script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}

xml=loadXMLDoc("ProgramList.xml");
path="/ProgramList/Program/*";
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    var nodes=xml.selectNodes(path);

    for (i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
    {
    document.write(nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("<br />");
    }
}

// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
{
    var nodes=xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var result=nodes.iterateNext();

    while (result)
    {
        document.write(result.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("<br />");
        result=nodes.iterateNext();
    }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I went to the site to check out the examples but I received unkown errors and the examples did not load.  So the link didn't help.  

I want to have 3 html pages.  

1st HTML page will give me all programs (Name) groupled by date. So only programs for today will show for both buildings.

I want the following results to display: 
<Name>
<Time>
<Room>
<Building>

2nd Html page will give me all programs (Name) grouped by date and building 1 (Centereach). So only todays programs will display for buidling 1.

3rd Html page to give me all programs (Name) grouped by date and building 2 (Selden).  Only today's programs will display for buidling 2 

I want the following results to dispaly for the 2nd and 3rd pages: 

<Name>
<Time>
<Room>

I also want the pages to update automaticaly as the date changes.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would only make sense to execute Xqueries on the server.  But then you'd still have to parse the response to extract the data you want to display from the result.

Bottom line:  If your dataset is large it's best to do the filtering (querying) on the server and only fetch the minimum set of data over the wire using Ajax.

But there is an option to use Xquery from the client side as well:
http://www.xqib.org/

Check it out and let me know if this helps.